# Magento 2.1 Custom module relationship

Tags: magento, magento2

I developed few custom modules for my Magento 2.1 store for smart manegmant of content in some of the CMS pages.

I used this tutorial https://www.ashsmith.io/magento2/module-from-scratch-introduction/ and this example https://github.com/ashsmith/magento2-blog-module-tutorial in order to do it.

Now, I have on page with list of FAQ, but each FAQ is belongs to FAQ Category (Not the Catalog Category).
So there is two custom modules here (FAQ Category and FAQ Question).
The FAQ Category only have Title field.
The FAQ Question have Title field, Answer (text editor) field, and FAQ Question dropdown (select box with list of all availble FAQ categories)

I don't know how to achive this.

What is the right way to do it? Especially the admin part.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to join fields. You cannot do this by using virtual type in di.xml, so you need to follow these steps and update your files

**#File etc/di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="namespace_modulename_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">Namespace\Modulename\Model\Resource\Modulename\Grid\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
</type>
<type name="Namespace\Modulename\Model\Resource\Modulename\Grid\Collection">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">tablename</argument>
        <argument name="eventPrefix" xsi:type="string">namespace_modulename_grid_collection</argument>
        <argument name="eventObject" xsi:type="string">namespace_grid_collection</argument>
        <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Namespace\Modulename\Model\Resource\Modulename</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

**In Your Resource Model File Model/Resource/Modulename/Collection.php**

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Modulename\Model\Resource\Modulename;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;

class Collection extends AbstractCollection
{
    /**
     * Define model & resource model
     */
    const YOUR_TABLE = 'tablename';

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface $connection = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource = null
    ) {
        $this->_init(
            'Namespace\Modulename\Model\Modulename',
            'Namespace\Modulename\Model\Resource\Modulename'
        );
        parent::__construct(
            $entityFactory, $logger, $fetchStrategy, $eventManager, $connection,
            $resource
        );
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }
    protected function _initSelect()
    {
        parent::_initSelect();

        $this->getSelect()->joinLeft(
                ['join_table' => $this->getTable('tablename')],
                'main_table.columnname = join_table.column_name',
                '*'
            );
    }
}
?>
```

**Now your Model/Resource/ModuleName/Grid/Collection.php**

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Modulename\Model\Resource\Modulename\Grid;

use Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchResultInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Search\AggregationInterface;
use Namespace\Modulename\Model\Resource\Modulename\Collection as ModulenameCollection;

/**
 * Class Collection
 * Collection for displaying grid
 */
class Collection extends ModulenameCollection implements SearchResultInterface
{
    /**
     * Resource initialization
     * @return $this
     */
   public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        $mainTable,
        $eventPrefix,
        $eventObject,
        $resourceModel,
        $model = 'Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\Document',
        $connection = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $entityFactory,
            $logger,
            $fetchStrategy,
            $eventManager,
            $storeManager,
            $connection,
            $resource
        );
        $this->_eventPrefix = $eventPrefix;
        $this->_eventObject = $eventObject;
        $this->_init($model, $resourceModel);
        $this->setMainTable($mainTable);
    }

    /**
     * @return AggregationInterface
     */
    public function getAggregations()
    {
        return $this->aggregations;
    }

    /**
     * @param AggregationInterface $aggregations
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setAggregations($aggregations)
    {
        $this->aggregations = $aggregations;
    }


    /**
     * Get search criteria.
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface|null
     */
    public function getSearchCriteria()
    {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Set search criteria.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria
     *
     * @return $this
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function setSearchCriteria(
        \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria = null
    ) {
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get total count.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getTotalCount()
    {
        return $this->getSize();
    }

    /**
     * Set total count.
     *
     * @param int $totalCount
     *
     * @return $this
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function setTotalCount($totalCount)
    {
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set items list.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensibleDataInterface[] $items
     *
     * @return $this
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function setItems(array $items = null)
    {
        return $this;
    }
}

?>
```

Now you can use the join table columns any where in your grid and when you call collection.

Comment: Not sure I understand, I need to have the 2 modules or only one?

Comment: You may have one module but you need to have two models one for FAQ Category and another for FAQ Question you can create relation by the above step.

Comment: this code is how you can join tables. So if you want to join faq question to faq category then use the above code in your question model and when you print your question model you will get the category values also.

Comment: Thats ok, but i'm asking how to create the admin part (CRUD) for question, I want to have the option when I adding a question to assign it to category (select box)

Comment: Its hard to explain each and every step in here. You can follow the reference tutorials you had given above to create a CRUD Model. The things you may have to change what I have given you the answer for.